# Not able to parse CTDataModel using Apache POI 3.13

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi, openxml

I am trying to programmatically update some text and change images in a SmartArt List object of a presentation file(.pptx) that is based on openxml format 2006. I was successful in searching and replacing text in the diagram data1.xml file by replaceAll method on the xml string but I am unable to parse the CTDataModel file using the CTDataModel.Factory.parse(File file) method

Below is the xml file of the Diagram data file. It has three bullet list containing text and embedded images as relationships. I need to get the modelId of the element where the text appears and the embedded image relationship and then change the target of that relationship to some other image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <dgm:dataModel 
        xmlns:dgm="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/diagram" 
        xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
        <dgm:ptLst>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{6E828954-E836-4BD0-9322-01425757D12F}" type="doc">
                <dgm:prSet loTypeId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList" loCatId="list" qsTypeId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2005/8/quickstyle/simple4" qsCatId="simple" csTypeId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2005/8/colors/accent6_2" csCatId="accent6" phldr="1"/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{1FE2E35A-12AB-4CE4-9E4D-12D87B7FDFFA}">
                <dgm:prSet custT="1"/>
                <dgm:spPr>
                    <a:noFill/>
                </dgm:spPr>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:pPr rtl="0"/>
                        <a:r>
                            <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="1800" dirty="0" smtClean="0"/>
                            <a:t>TEXT_TO_REPLACE_1</a:t>
                        </a:r>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1800" dirty="0"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{F2EF8CE4-27D6-484A-90E0-4014CC11265A}" type="parTrans" cxnId="{0C7C15A9-E9DC-45BA-A98B-C3764E94A709}">
                <dgm:prSet/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{BC0ED768-24E5-4223-9AC9-FA49E959BBB8}" type="sibTrans" cxnId="{0C7C15A9-E9DC-45BA-A98B-C3764E94A709}">
                <dgm:prSet/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{AE017508-C3D7-4D8A-BBF2-0210789EACA4}">
                <dgm:prSet custT="1"/>
                <dgm:spPr>
                    <a:noFill/>
                </dgm:spPr>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:pPr rtl="0"/>
                        <a:r>
                            <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="1800" dirty="0" smtClean="0"/>
                            <a:t>TEXT_TO_REPLACE_2</a:t>
                        </a:r>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1800" dirty="0"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{45BA471A-EB29-48B5-A787-D53143938D0C}" type="parTrans" cxnId="{67ADBEDD-9195-4B40-A75C-CDF23813823E}">
                <dgm:prSet/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{E2796C20-8868-4DB7-9502-63CFC0E8753B}" type="sibTrans" cxnId="{67ADBEDD-9195-4B40-A75C-CDF23813823E}">
                <dgm:prSet/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{95A7619D-EE01-4231-9592-D698A93B2322}">
                <dgm:prSet custT="1"/>
                <dgm:spPr>
                    <a:noFill/>
                </dgm:spPr>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:pPr rtl="0"/>
                        <a:r>                        
                            <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="1800" dirty="0" smtClean="0"/>
                            <a:t>TEXT_TO_REPLACE_3</a:t>
                        </a:r>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1800" dirty="0"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{068714CB-B91F-401C-B4E0-B84378440430}" type="parTrans" cxnId="{29CEF007-255C-401D-BC89-D95CB5347B97}">
                <dgm:prSet/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{3DFEDCED-3FAD-4BD3-A065-E15D56A7F27F}" type="sibTrans" cxnId="{29CEF007-255C-401D-BC89-D95CB5347B97}">
                <dgm:prSet/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{08F6EB28-75AD-4850-AAB7-B04C1DFF72DC}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{6E828954-E836-4BD0-9322-01425757D12F}" presName="Name0" presStyleCnt="0">
                    <dgm:presLayoutVars>
                        <dgm:chMax val="7"/>
                        <dgm:chPref val="7"/>
                        <dgm:dir/>
                    </dgm:presLayoutVars>
                </dgm:prSet>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{6FE0EDBB-C7E9-4A8C-A872-13084DA196BC}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{6E828954-E836-4BD0-9322-01425757D12F}" presName="Name1" presStyleCnt="0"/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{E80E6BD4-B243-45F8-8674-F2FF8DD91C50}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{6E828954-E836-4BD0-9322-01425757D12F}" presName="cycle" presStyleCnt="0"/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{095A698B-B03C-4AB8-89FB-D069EA405182}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{6E828954-E836-4BD0-9322-01425757D12F}" presName="srcNode" presStyleLbl="node1" presStyleIdx="0" presStyleCnt="3"/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{16CC9F8E-6CF4-4834-93AB-676B9823962F}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{6E828954-E836-4BD0-9322-01425757D12F}" presName="conn" presStyleLbl="parChTrans1D2" presStyleIdx="0" presStyleCnt="1"/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{B1F82AB7-F600-4F0F-A819-0E13DB3F39A5}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{6E828954-E836-4BD0-9322-01425757D12F}" presName="extraNode" presStyleLbl="node1" presStyleIdx="0" presStyleCnt="3"/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{AEF027AF-ADD4-41C2-AC2B-13FEDE32C415}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{6E828954-E836-4BD0-9322-01425757D12F}" presName="dstNode" presStyleLbl="node1" presStyleIdx="0" presStyleCnt="3"/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{D41980AA-D309-43F0-BF58-012F2E3D583A}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{95A7619D-EE01-4231-9592-D698A93B2322}" presName="text_1" presStyleLbl="node1" presStyleIdx="0" presStyleCnt="3" custScaleY="100000">
                    <dgm:presLayoutVars>
                        <dgm:bulletEnabled val="1"/>
                    </dgm:presLayoutVars>
                </dgm:prSet>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{C0587850-10BA-48AC-9C96-F2E8DDB81A9C}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{95A7619D-EE01-4231-9592-D698A93B2322}" presName="accent_1" presStyleCnt="0"/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{51DE7F31-6056-41CF-A1F8-5E4E6F252F69}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{95A7619D-EE01-4231-9592-D698A93B2322}" presName="accentRepeatNode" presStyleLbl="solidFgAcc1" presStyleIdx="0" presStyleCnt="3" custScaleX="80000" custScaleY="80000" custLinFactNeighborX="-120" custLinFactNeighborY="-3293"/>
                <dgm:spPr>
                    <a:blipFill dpi="0" rotWithShape="1">
                        <a:blip 
                            xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" r:embed="rId1">
                            <a:extLst>
                                <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                                    <a14:useLocalDpi 
                                        xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
                                </a:ext>
                            </a:extLst>
                        </a:blip>
                        <a:srcRect/>
                        <a:stretch>
                            <a:fillRect/>
                        </a:stretch>
                    </a:blipFill>
                    <a:effectLst>
                        <a:innerShdw blurRad="63500" dist="50800">
                            <a:prstClr val="black">
                                <a:alpha val="50000"/>
                            </a:prstClr>
                        </a:innerShdw>
                        <a:softEdge rad="12700"/>
                    </a:effectLst>
                </dgm:spPr>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{53F8E7B3-14F1-47DB-8D1A-02FE4CCB21A0}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{AE017508-C3D7-4D8A-BBF2-0210789EACA4}" presName="text_2" presStyleLbl="node1" presStyleIdx="1" presStyleCnt="3" custScaleX="103369">
                    <dgm:presLayoutVars>
                        <dgm:bulletEnabled val="1"/>
                    </dgm:presLayoutVars>
                </dgm:prSet>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{7CCDD84D-8793-46A5-97DD-F61AD62325F9}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{AE017508-C3D7-4D8A-BBF2-0210789EACA4}" presName="accent_2" presStyleCnt="0"/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{FB3CBAC5-6093-4CB4-AF8F-E7B57FB40A72}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{AE017508-C3D7-4D8A-BBF2-0210789EACA4}" presName="accentRepeatNode" presStyleLbl="solidFgAcc1" presStyleIdx="1" presStyleCnt="3" custScaleX="80000" custScaleY="80000"/>
                <dgm:spPr>
                    <a:blipFill dpi="0" rotWithShape="1">
                        <a:blip 
                            xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" r:embed="rId2">
                            <a:extLst>
                                <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                                    <a14:useLocalDpi 
                                        xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
                                </a:ext>
                            </a:extLst>
                        </a:blip>
                        <a:srcRect/>
                        <a:stretch>
                            <a:fillRect/>
                        </a:stretch>
                    </a:blipFill>
                    <a:effectLst>
                        <a:innerShdw blurRad="63500" dist="50800">
                            <a:prstClr val="black">
                                <a:alpha val="50000"/>
                            </a:prstClr>
                        </a:innerShdw>
                        <a:softEdge rad="12700"/>
                    </a:effectLst>
                </dgm:spPr>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{FFD3804D-110E-4588-A985-472E18ED558D}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{1FE2E35A-12AB-4CE4-9E4D-12D87B7FDFFA}" presName="text_3" presStyleLbl="node1" presStyleIdx="2" presStyleCnt="3">
                    <dgm:presLayoutVars>
                        <dgm:bulletEnabled val="1"/>
                    </dgm:presLayoutVars>
                </dgm:prSet>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{D8E95FD7-3C8F-4AD2-B6A0-3B58091DB0D0}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{1FE2E35A-12AB-4CE4-9E4D-12D87B7FDFFA}" presName="accent_3" presStyleCnt="0"/>
                <dgm:spPr/>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
            <dgm:pt modelId="{8ECB4450-30D8-4309-B2D8-B5E9CFB2B24D}" type="pres">
                <dgm:prSet presAssocID="{1FE2E35A-12AB-4CE4-9E4D-12D87B7FDFFA}" presName="accentRepeatNode" presStyleLbl="solidFgAcc1" presStyleIdx="2" presStyleCnt="3" custScaleX="80000" custScaleY="80000"/>
                <dgm:spPr>
                    <a:blipFill dpi="0" rotWithShape="1">
                        <a:blip 
                            xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" r:embed="rId3">
                            <a:extLst>
                                <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                                    <a14:useLocalDpi 
                                        xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
                                </a:ext>
                            </a:extLst>
                        </a:blip>
                        <a:srcRect/>
                        <a:stretch>
                            <a:fillRect/>
                        </a:stretch>
                    </a:blipFill>
                    <a:effectLst>
                        <a:innerShdw blurRad="63500" dist="50800">
                            <a:prstClr val="black">
                                <a:alpha val="50000"/>
                            </a:prstClr>
                        </a:innerShdw>
                        <a:softEdge rad="12700"/>
                    </a:effectLst>
                </dgm:spPr>
                <dgm:t>
                    <a:bodyPr/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/>
                    </a:p>
                </dgm:t>
            </dgm:pt>
        </dgm:ptLst>
        <dgm:cxnLst>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{67ADBEDD-9195-4B40-A75C-CDF23813823E}" srcId="{6E828954-E836-4BD0-9322-01425757D12F}" destId="{AE017508-C3D7-4D8A-BBF2-0210789EACA4}" srcOrd="1" destOrd="0" parTransId="{45BA471A-EB29-48B5-A787-D53143938D0C}" sibTransId="{E2796C20-8868-4DB7-9502-63CFC0E8753B}"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{0C7C15A9-E9DC-45BA-A98B-C3764E94A709}" srcId="{6E828954-E836-4BD0-9322-01425757D12F}" destId="{1FE2E35A-12AB-4CE4-9E4D-12D87B7FDFFA}" srcOrd="2" destOrd="0" parTransId="{F2EF8CE4-27D6-484A-90E0-4014CC11265A}" sibTransId="{BC0ED768-24E5-4223-9AC9-FA49E959BBB8}"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{29CEF007-255C-401D-BC89-D95CB5347B97}" srcId="{6E828954-E836-4BD0-9322-01425757D12F}" destId="{95A7619D-EE01-4231-9592-D698A93B2322}" srcOrd="0" destOrd="0" parTransId="{068714CB-B91F-401C-B4E0-B84378440430}" sibTransId="{3DFEDCED-3FAD-4BD3-A065-E15D56A7F27F}"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{07274767-024F-469B-BA85-BB067318BA3B}" type="presOf" srcId="{AE017508-C3D7-4D8A-BBF2-0210789EACA4}" destId="{53F8E7B3-14F1-47DB-8D1A-02FE4CCB21A0}" srcOrd="0" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{B4C43AFD-6BBB-4D36-B616-DD184EBFAABE}" type="presOf" srcId="{3DFEDCED-3FAD-4BD3-A065-E15D56A7F27F}" destId="{16CC9F8E-6CF4-4834-93AB-676B9823962F}" srcOrd="0" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{7C2D3A83-36E8-4BBB-A140-A0BB3155949A}" type="presOf" srcId="{95A7619D-EE01-4231-9592-D698A93B2322}" destId="{D41980AA-D309-43F0-BF58-012F2E3D583A}" srcOrd="0" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{C0CE365C-3217-472E-BB2D-DFD6958D6F5C}" type="presOf" srcId="{1FE2E35A-12AB-4CE4-9E4D-12D87B7FDFFA}" destId="{FFD3804D-110E-4588-A985-472E18ED558D}" srcOrd="0" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{9B034817-56CC-49B7-9D86-53986FEC3EC6}" type="presOf" srcId="{6E828954-E836-4BD0-9322-01425757D12F}" destId="{08F6EB28-75AD-4850-AAB7-B04C1DFF72DC}" srcOrd="0" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{F8E50B03-C5A0-41D8-A4CD-4BF30BFD3617}" type="presParOf" srcId="{08F6EB28-75AD-4850-AAB7-B04C1DFF72DC}" destId="{6FE0EDBB-C7E9-4A8C-A872-13084DA196BC}" srcOrd="0" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{22875B8E-C78A-491B-B361-85B064AD6B2F}" type="presParOf" srcId="{6FE0EDBB-C7E9-4A8C-A872-13084DA196BC}" destId="{E80E6BD4-B243-45F8-8674-F2FF8DD91C50}" srcOrd="0" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{AE41C528-D054-4D0F-BC56-00513E76A835}" type="presParOf" srcId="{E80E6BD4-B243-45F8-8674-F2FF8DD91C50}" destId="{095A698B-B03C-4AB8-89FB-D069EA405182}" srcOrd="0" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{0CAC7FBB-4FCC-4C31-8DDB-75D4FF020F3A}" type="presParOf" srcId="{E80E6BD4-B243-45F8-8674-F2FF8DD91C50}" destId="{16CC9F8E-6CF4-4834-93AB-676B9823962F}" srcOrd="1" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{81DD28E5-6B39-4219-BE68-06D32851B88A}" type="presParOf" srcId="{E80E6BD4-B243-45F8-8674-F2FF8DD91C50}" destId="{B1F82AB7-F600-4F0F-A819-0E13DB3F39A5}" srcOrd="2" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{728308AD-00D4-470B-BCA6-1B0433E6B6C3}" type="presParOf" srcId="{E80E6BD4-B243-45F8-8674-F2FF8DD91C50}" destId="{AEF027AF-ADD4-41C2-AC2B-13FEDE32C415}" srcOrd="3" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{1D139609-24D3-4143-95B0-3584780F46B0}" type="presParOf" srcId="{6FE0EDBB-C7E9-4A8C-A872-13084DA196BC}" destId="{D41980AA-D309-43F0-BF58-012F2E3D583A}" srcOrd="1" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{01C332E3-27A2-462E-B14B-8C3D416E54F4}" type="presParOf" srcId="{6FE0EDBB-C7E9-4A8C-A872-13084DA196BC}" destId="{C0587850-10BA-48AC-9C96-F2E8DDB81A9C}" srcOrd="2" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{8162F157-AABD-49AD-BD95-2D701CB9B8DC}" type="presParOf" srcId="{C0587850-10BA-48AC-9C96-F2E8DDB81A9C}" destId="{51DE7F31-6056-41CF-A1F8-5E4E6F252F69}" srcOrd="0" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{BAAFA36C-E721-488E-92FB-64E1A52226E5}" type="presParOf" srcId="{6FE0EDBB-C7E9-4A8C-A872-13084DA196BC}" destId="{53F8E7B3-14F1-47DB-8D1A-02FE4CCB21A0}" srcOrd="3" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{A0CC870B-7A48-4869-8682-B6F4CE0C025A}" type="presParOf" srcId="{6FE0EDBB-C7E9-4A8C-A872-13084DA196BC}" destId="{7CCDD84D-8793-46A5-97DD-F61AD62325F9}" srcOrd="4" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{584BA6DD-2531-48B5-A540-40CB102C2360}" type="presParOf" srcId="{7CCDD84D-8793-46A5-97DD-F61AD62325F9}" destId="{FB3CBAC5-6093-4CB4-AF8F-E7B57FB40A72}" srcOrd="0" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{5F2DD8CD-58A5-4327-AB5F-19804D01C4F2}" type="presParOf" srcId="{6FE0EDBB-C7E9-4A8C-A872-13084DA196BC}" destId="{FFD3804D-110E-4588-A985-472E18ED558D}" srcOrd="5" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{E5806161-AE73-4965-AEB2-DC525D965B99}" type="presParOf" srcId="{6FE0EDBB-C7E9-4A8C-A872-13084DA196BC}" destId="{D8E95FD7-3C8F-4AD2-B6A0-3B58091DB0D0}" srcOrd="6" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
            <dgm:cxn modelId="{A8E23FD6-A108-42FB-8935-BEA88C74FF1A}" type="presParOf" srcId="{D8E95FD7-3C8F-4AD2-B6A0-3B58091DB0D0}" destId="{8ECB4450-30D8-4309-B2D8-B5E9CFB2B24D}" srcOrd="0" destOrd="0" presId="urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2008/layout/VerticalCurvedList"/>
        </dgm:cxnLst>
        <dgm:bg/>
        <dgm:whole/>
        <dgm:extLst>
            <a:ext uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2008/diagram">
                <dsp:dataModelExt 
                    xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2008/diagram" relId="rId10" minVer="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/diagram"/>
            </a:ext>
        </dgm:extLst>
    </dgm:dataModel>
```

Below is the code that tries to parse the CTDataModel from its xml file

```
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.diagram.CTDataModel;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.diagram.CTPtList;

String file = "/Users/xyz/Documents/testppt/ppt/diagrams/data1.xml";
CTDataModel dataModel = CTDataModel.Factory.parse(new FileInputStream(file));
CTPtList ptLst = dataModel.getPtLst();
```

The above code always returns null in ptLst.

The Apache POI 3.13 contains

[image: The Apache POI 3.13 library contains]

If there is any other way to implement then please let me know.

Comment: Please try DataModelDocument.Factory.parse(...) instead, usually you can't parse the input data with the xml type itself, but with the enclosing element/type

Comment: @kiwiwings It worked, thanks a lot! You can post your comment as answer so that I can accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When parsing xml elements with [XMLBeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/), which are used by [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) as the xml mapping layer, you need to look for the corresponding parent element of that xml element.

For the xml files inside the [Office Open XML](http://officeopenxml.com/) containers (.xlsx,.pptx,.docx are zip files), you will usually find a ...Document class in the [poi-ooxml-schemas](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22poi-ooxml-schemas%22) (reduced version) or the [ooxml-schemas](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22ooxml-schemas%22) (full version)
Simply search the (binary) jar for `CT<capitalized element name>` matches - so in your case `dgm:dataModel` becomes `CTDataModel`, but instead of using the CTDataModel class, you need to search for a class referencing that class.
In your case `DataModelDocument` was the enclosing class, but this also applies to in-between xml types (, which don't have that `...Document` naming) .

Be aware that certain type names like `CTShape` will be in more than one package, which reflects the xml namespace - so of course you need use the correct namespace then ...